# Can't pass in struct into function for pthread_create correctly

Tags: pthreads

I'm trying to pass in a Professor struct into my professor function but I can't properly get the information stored in it to pass into the function. I suspect it has something to do with how I malloc'd p but I thought freeing after it's completed would solve that problem. I get a segfault when I try to print *professor->id, because apparently it decides to read p as memory location 0x0, even though it's not in main

```
typedef struct{
    int *id;
    int *assignings;
    int *min_wait;
    int *max_wait;
    int *min_assignments;
    int *max_assignments;
    int *min_hrs;
    int *max_hrs;
} Professor;

Professor* makeProfessor(){
    Professor *professor = malloc(sizeof *professor);
    return professor;
}

void * professorFunc(void *p){
    Professor *professor = (Professor*)p;
    fprintf(stdout,"Starting Professor %d\n", *professor->id);
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
//Creating threads
    pthread_t professor[num_professors];
    Professor *p;
    int i;
    int id;
    for(i = 0; i < num_professors; ++i){
            id = i + 1;
            p = malloc (sizeof *p);
            p->id = &id;
            if(pthread_create(&professor[i], NULL, professorFunc, (void*)p) != 0){
                    perror("pthread_create");
                    exit(1);
            }
            free(p);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < num_professors; ++i){
            if(pthread_join(professor[i], NULL) != 0){
                    perror("pthread_join");
                    exit(1);
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are allocating the array of Professor structs, and immediately freeing them, likely before your thread has the chance to operate on them. A better way to implement this, would be to allocate the whole array, process them, and then free the memory, once you know the threads have exited (example below).

```
pthread_t professor[num_professors];
Professor *p;
int i;
int id;
p = malloc (sizeof(*p) * num_professors);
for(i = 0; i < num_professors; ++i){
        id = i + 1;
        p->id = &id;
        if(pthread_create(&professor[i], NULL, professorFunc, (void*)p) != 0){
                perror("pthread_create");
                exit(1);
        }
}
for(i = 0; i < num_professors; ++i){
        if(pthread_join(professor[i], NULL) != 0){
                perror("pthread_join");
                exit(1);
        }
}
free(p);
```

Comment: Well that solves the segfault. Awesome. Now I keep getting *professor->id to equal 2, instead of 1 and 2 respectively

num_professors default is 2, and when I put it as 10, I get various things
`Starting Professor 3'
'Starting Professor 4'
'Starting Professor 5'
Id: 5
'Starting Professor 3'
Id: 6
'Starting Professor 6'
Id: 7
'Starting Professor 7'
'Starting Professor 8'
Id: 8
Id: 9
'Starting Professor 9'
Id: 10
'Starting Professor 10'
'Starting Professor 10`

Comment: It is because your `id` field in the struct is using a pointer. This points to the address of the local variable `id`, which you update every loop. Your thread function will see whatever value is the current one, when the thread executes the print statement. You probably want the (all) fields to be just ints, not pointers to ints.